# Prevent JavaScript from bubbling up the DOM when using the HTMLElement.click() method

Tags: javascript

I know this looks strange, but I have a situation where I need to simulate a click event when we hover over the target.

I am currently using JavaScript's `.click()` method – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click, but the click is bubbling up to the `li` in the DOM and triggering `activateAnchor()` function at the same time. I have tried using `stopPropagation`, but this is having no effect.

My question is: Is this even possible or do I need to approach this issue in a different way.

I have an example here – https://jsfiddle.net/dryrobe/vsq7czmx/43/

```
const output = document.querySelector('.output');
const switcherList = document.querySelector('[data-custom-switcher]');
const switcherListItems = Array.from(switcherList.getElementsByTagName('li'));
const switcherListItemsAnchors = Array.from(switcherList.getElementsByTagName('a'));

switcherListItemsAnchors.map(switcherListItemAnchor => switcherListItemAnchor.addEventListener('mouseenter', simulateClick.bind(switcherListItemAnchor)));
switcherListItems.map(switcherListItem => switcherListItem.addEventListener('click', activateAnchor.bind(switcherListItem)));

// This should only fire when each item is clicked, but it fires on hover.
function activateAnchor() {
  event.stopPropagation();
  addMessage('activateAnchor');
}

// This should fire when each item is hovered
function simulateClick() {
  event.stopPropagation();
  this.click();
  addMessage('simulateClick');
}

function addMessage(message) {
  if(message === 'activateAnchor') {
    output.innerHTML += `<h1>This is the activateAnchor function</h1>`;
  }
  if(message === 'simulateClick') {
    output.innerHTML += `<h1>This is the simulateClick function</h1>`;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.click()` will result in a propagating click event. If you want the click event to not propagate, you'll have to add a click listener and call `stopPropagation` on that event. You can't stop the *click* event from propagating from inside the *mouseenter* handler. Check `e.isTrusted` to see if the event was triggered by Javascript or by the user actually clicking - if false, it was triggered by Javascript, and you can call `stopPropagation`:

```
switcherListItemsAnchors.forEach((switcherListItemAnchor) => {
  switcherListItemAnchor.addEventListener('mouseenter', simulateClick.bind(switcherListItemAnchor))
  switcherListItemAnchor.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (!e.isTrusted) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  })
});
```

Also note that you should only use `.map` for creating one array from another. For side-effects (such as adding listeners), use `forEach` instead.

There's also no need to `.bind` if the `this` inside the bound function is intended to be the clicked element already (or if `this` is not used inside the function):

```js
const output = document.querySelector('.output');
const switcherList = document.querySelector('[data-custom-switcher]');

switcherList.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((switcherListItemAnchor) => {
  switcherListItemAnchor.addEventListener('mouseenter', simulateClick)
  switcherListItemAnchor.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (!e.isTrusted) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  })
});
switcherList.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(switcherListItem => {
  switcherListItem.addEventListener('click', activateAnchor);
});

// This should only fire when each item is clicked, but it fires on hover.
function activateAnchor() {
  addMessage('activateAnchor');
}

// This should fire when each item is hovered
function simulateClick(e) {
  this.click();
  addMessage('simulateClick');
}

function addMessage(message) {
  if (message === 'activateAnchor') {
    output.innerHTML += `<h1>This is the activateAnchor function</h1>`;
  }
  if (message === 'simulateClick') {
    output.innerHTML += `<h1>This is the simulateClick function</h1>`;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.output {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

li+li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

a {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="output"></div>

<ul data-custom-switcher>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great answer, this is it. I see the `isTrusted` method is not supported in IE-11, but it looks like this is the best solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

But why are you using .click(), I would just do this...

```
<div onclick="if(event.stopPropagation){event.stopPropagation();}" onmouseover="RunSomeFunction();">Some Message</div>
```

Comment: I am overriding a UIKit Switcher component and there is no way to change the event listener. The Switcher – https://getuikit.com/docs/switcher listens for a click by default, but in my instance I want this component to trigger when a link is hovered.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a full [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent), which by default won't bubble. You just need to dispatch it like you called `click()`.

```
function simulateClick(e) {
  const click = new MouseEvent('click');
  this.dispatchEvent(click);
  addMessage('simulateClick');
}
```

```js
const output = document.querySelector('.output');
const switcherList = document.querySelector('[data-custom-switcher]');

switcherList.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((switcherListItemAnchor) => {
  switcherListItemAnchor.addEventListener('mouseenter', simulateClick)
  });
switcherList.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(switcherListItem => {
  switcherListItem.addEventListener('click', activateAnchor);
});

// This should only fire when each item is clicked, but it fires on hover.
function activateAnchor() {
  addMessage('activateAnchor');
}

// This should fire when each item is hovered
function simulateClick(e) {
  const click = new MouseEvent('click');
  this.dispatchEvent(click);
  addMessage('simulateClick');
}

function addMessage(message) {
  if (message === 'activateAnchor') {
    output.innerHTML += `<h1>This is the activateAnchor function</h1>`;
  }
  if (message === 'simulateClick') {
    output.innerHTML += `<h1>This is the simulateClick function</h1>`;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.output {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

li+li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

a {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="output"></div>

<ul data-custom-switcher>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```